# This move constructor of Microsoft example appears to have redundant code

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx) for developers has this code snippet:

```
// Move constructor.  
MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other) : _data(nullptr), _length(0)  
{  
   std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = "   
             << other._length << ". Moving resource." << std::endl;  

   // Copy the data pointer and its length from source object.  
   _data = other._data;      // Assginment 1
   _length = other._length;  // Assignment 2

   // Release the data pointer from the source object so that  
   // the destructor does not free the memory multiple times.  
   other._data = nullptr;  
   other._length = 0;  
}
```

What's the use of `_data(nullptr)`, `_length(0)`, when the instructions labelled **Assignment 1** and **Assignment 2** over-write the values of `_data` and `_length`?

Comment: What do you mean by "memory-initialized"?

Comment: Good habits are worth more than nano-optimisations.

Comment: @juanchopanza When the member variables are initialized before the opening brace of the constructor is seen. I am not able to remember the exact reference, but this term (mem-initializer) is used in one of the popular C++ literature. Memory initialization is the only way by which earlier C++ versions allowed const and reference members' initialization.

Comment: Also, this code calls methods that could throw exceptions, which is poor practice for a move constructor.

Comment: @SeshadriR yeah, i don't think that is called "memory initialization". Anyway, the code seems quite redundant.

Comment: My bad. It is called mem-initializer per **Annotated Reference Manual** (12.6.2 Initializing bases and members). I have erroneously assumed and expanded *mem* as *memory*, while it should have been *member*. Really, bad memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely it should be

```
// Move constructor.  
MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other) : _data(other._data), _length(other._length)
{  
   std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = "   
             << other._length << ". Moving resource." << std::endl;  

   // Release the data pointer from the source object so that  
   // the destructor does not free the memory multiple times.  
   other._data = nullptr;  
   other._length = 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For safety.

Let's say that for some reason, `other._data` and/or `other._length` fail to access their value (most probably the pointer `other._data` though).

An example could be that the pointer is pointing to invalid memory and produce a Segmentation Fault (since you may access memory that is not own by your program), and the program to crash at that point. Another possibility is that `other` is `*nullptr`, and so on... What are the values of `_data` and `_length` then? Undefined.

It would be nice for these two to have their initial value, since that might help debugging, since the programmer can think that since these two have their initial values, maybe there is something wrong in the assignment.

Comment: When you say "the pointer to be invalid", you mean that on Window the validity of a pointer value is checked when it is assigned?

Comment: `other` could be  `*nullptr`, thus `other._data` may crash

Comment: @Oliv I am talking about pointers pointing to invalid memory.

Comment: @gsamaras, indeed if `other` is a dangling reference, dereferencing it may produce a processor exception, but is not it the only possible cause of process termination?

Comment: No it's not @Oliv. Many things can crash a program in general.

Comment: @gsamaras, I do not know any hardware/implementation where assignment to a raw pointer checks validity of a pointers. The other causes of program terminations for exemple a stack overflow, or hardware fault can happen anywhere between the constructor call site and member initialization, so there are no point in considering these faults to justify these redundant member initialization!!

Comment: @pqnet If `other` were a null-**reference**, the code would already be firmly within UB territory. There's no way of fixing that after the fact. As far as the C++ standard is concerned, there is no such thing as a null-reference, so the access of `other`'s members must succeed. This answer would be valid if `other` were passed as a pointer, but that is not the case here.